# C# openid-connect server & client implementation with .NET Core 5+, (MSAL?) and Keycloak

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This question has been asked before but it has been long enough I feel its appropriate to ask again since the previous answers were .NET 2.

I have a recent installation of keycloak setup and working providing a single sign on experience with a couple apps.  Now for the real reason keycloak was setup, to use with developing and accessing webapis.  I'm working to switch away from using ADAL & MS ADFS on prem to MSAL & keycloak.

Based on previous answers, server side I have installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect NuGet Package (after giving up on trying to get Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer to work) and client side have been trying to use MSAL.  (I'm not stuck on these technologies, just what I've found so far, if I should be using something else please say so.)

Current attempt Server side:
Inside Startup.cs, inside public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://keycloak.mydomain.net/auth/realms/myrealm/";
                options.ClientId = "client_id";
                options.ClientSecret = "client_secret";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
            });
```

Current attempt Client side:

```
            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
                    .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUri)
                    //.WithExtraQueryParameters(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "resource", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(RedirectUri) } })
                    .Build();

            //IPublicClientApplication app = builder.Build();
            IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

            //string[] scopes = new string[] { "openid", "profile", "allatclaims" };
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "openid", "profile" }; //, "offline_access" };
            Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult result = null;
            try
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        //.WithExtraQueryParameters(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "resource", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(RedirectUri) } })
                        .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex_a)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("(1a) msal: " + ex_a.Message +", code: "+ ex_a.ErrorCode);

                try
                {
                    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                            //.WithExtraQueryParameters(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "resource", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(RedirectUri) } })
                            .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("(1b) msal: " + e.Message +", code: "+ e.HResult);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("(2) msal: " + e.Message +", code: "+ e.HResult);
            }
```

Looking for an example of the right way to do this or a fix for the code I currently have.

The error I haven't been able to get past is [AADSTS50049](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes). Could it be that MSAL will only support on prem ms adfs & azure by design?

Comment: Perhaps I’m missing something, but I don’t understand what your actual question is here?

Comment: I'm looking for an example of how to do it, or help with the code I currently have.

Comment: for webapis, generally you add a service account so you can authenticate without a web UI.  If it is a web just calling back on the api then normal auth should be fine

Comment: In this case I have a mobile app and desktop app, both which interact with the webapi and need to be able to be identified by the webapi.  The thing is I had this all working with on prem adfs & ADAL, moving to .net core 5 meant I needed to switch to MSAL, but MSAL wasn't working with on prem adfs (bug filed and acknowledged by ms) so I installed keycloak and am working to switch over to keycloak, not sure how to set the values or which nuget package I should be using.  Not finding a good example out on the net.  The best I've found was with .net version 2.

Comment: We are facing a similar issue with msal and keycloak. Did you find a solution? What approach did you end up following?